# Encode the size of a binary encoding with Data.Binary

Tags: sockets, haskell, binary-data

I'm working with a wire protocol that politely encodes the total length of the message in bytes as an Int32le in the first 4 bytes of the message. This seems like a pretty common use case, but I don't see an obvious function for it in `Data.Binary`.  Is there a standard way to handle encode to a format like this?

Also while I have you, is there a standard way to read a protocol like this with `Network.Socket`?  I think I read the first 4 bytes decode them then use that number to read the rest of the message.

---

For context, here is [the BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html).  We are trying to write packed Vectors into the custom binary fields (0x80-0xFF in the `binary` element) which is not supported by [the current BSON library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson) so we need to do a bit of our own encoding.

Comment: You really mean `Int32le` and not `Word32le` for a length?

Comment: God as my witness it is Int32le.  I reread the spec a few times just to be sure. http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

Comment: Hmm, you're right. It seems like an awful wart in the spec to use a signed value for a length like that, though.

Comment: If this is about BSON in particular, rather than how to do this sort of thing in general, then why not just use the `bson` package? (And possibly `bson-mapping` too)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it. I'm not sure which piece you think needs an extra utility function.

Server/sender:

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Put
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Network.Run.TCP
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy

sendWithLength :: Binary a => Socket -> a -> IO ()
sendWithLength s payload = do
  let payloadBS = encode payload
  let payloadLen = BS.length payloadBS
  let payloadLenBS = runPut $ putInt32le $ fromIntegral payloadLen
  sendAll s payloadLenBS
  sendAll s payloadBS

handleClient :: Socket -> IO ()
handleClient s = do
  sendWithLength s "Hello, World!"
  sendWithLength s ([123, 45, 678] :: [Int])

main :: IO ()
main = runTCPServer Nothing "3000" handleClient
```

Client/receiver:

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Int
import Network.Run.TCP
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy

-- Like recv, but doesn't return a partial result unless the socket reaches
-- EOF.
recvAll :: Socket -> Int64 -> IO BS.ByteString
recvAll s n = do
  bytes <- recv s n
  let len = BS.length bytes
  if BS.null bytes || BS.length bytes == n
    then
      return bytes
    else do
      bytes' <- recvAll s (n - len)
      return $ bytes <> bytes'

recvWithLength :: Binary a => Socket -> IO a
recvWithLength s = do
  payloadLenBS <- recvAll s 4
  let payloadLen = fromIntegral $ runGet getInt32le payloadLenBS
  payloadBS <- recvAll s payloadLen
  let payload = decode payloadBS
  return payload

handleServer :: Socket -> IO ()
handleServer s = do
  payload1 <- recvWithLength s
  putStrLn payload1
  payload2 <- recvWithLength s
  print (payload2 :: [Int])

main :: IO ()
main = runTCPClient "127.0.0.1" "3000" handleServer
```

By the way, `Network.Run.TCP` is from [the `network-run` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-run-0.2.2).

Comment: I should clarify that BSON is recursive so I need to be able to put the lengths in the LBS not merely send them to the socket.